# create UIPopOverController in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create UIPopOverController in iPad. And this UIPopOverController is open when tap on the UIBarButonItem which is display programtically.

```
    UIButton *btnRight = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnRight setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.PNG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnRight.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
    [btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDone) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *btnRightBarItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnRight];

    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:btnRightBarItem];
```

My selector code is :

```
- (void)pressDone:(id)sender
{
     PopoverViewController *PopoverView =[[PopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopoverViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:PopoverView];
    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

When I use above code,I get error,

```
[HrOfferDetailVC pressDone]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73bb670'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method name is `pressDone:` not `pressDone`

```
[btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

will do the job

You have add target as self and self here i think is `HrOfferDetailVC` so the method should be declared in .h and it should be implemented in `HrOfferDetailVC.m`

Use this code to show popover

```
- (void)pressDone:(id)sender 
{ 
UIButton *buttonItem=(UIButton *)sender; 

PopoverViewController *PopoverView =[[PopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopoverViewController" bundle:nil]; 
self.popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:PopoverView]; 

[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:buttonItem.frame inView:buttonItem.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; 

}
```

Comment: I add : after pressDone but still same error occur. [btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: @kels there is a method in that view controller `- (void)pressDone:(id)sender` , and it is declared in .h ?

Comment: Yes, there is - (void)pressDone:(id)sender method in viewController.h file.

Comment: Is it there in `HrOfferDetailVC` viewcontroller?It should be declared there

Comment: Yes, that my mistake, I have declare in HrOfferDetailVC.h But still same error occur.

Comment: and method is there in `HrOfferDetailVC.m`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34037/discussion-between-lithu-t-v-and-kels)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

replace following line

```
[btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDone) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

with

```
[btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Explanation**

Add `:` sign after `pressDone` button. Because you pass one parameter in method definition i.e.

```
- (void)pressDone:(id)sender
```

And you don't pass any argument in method calling... so, the error is occurred because the method is not found in code without argument.

Comment: I add : after pressDone but still same error occur.    [btnRight addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];